# Trying to make a photo filter's effects cumulative on the photo-java swing

Tags: java, swing, jslider, changelistener

Basically I have made an interface that displays a picture and it has multiple JSliders.  Each one has a different function such as blur, brighten, and saturate.   I have implemented the sliders in such a way that I override the stateChanged method when adding a new slider.  This works fine when I do the sliders individually, however it changes back to the original picture once I use a different slider.  I want to make it so that it the picture accumulates the filters on the photo.  Any suggestions?  Here is an example of one of my sliders.

```
brightSlider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

            JSlider source = (JSlider) e.getSource();
            double scaleValue = source.getValue() / 100.0;
            Picture newPic = new PictureImpl(picture.getWidth(), picture.getHeight());
            //Picture newPic = picture;
            Pixel zeroPixel = new ColorPixel(0, 0, 0);
            Pixel p;
            for (int i = 0; i < picture.getWidth(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < picture.getHeight(); j++) {
                    newPic.setPixel(i, j, zeroPixel);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < picture.getWidth(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < picture.getHeight(); j++) {
                    if (scaleValue > 0) {
                        p = picture.getPixel(i, j).lighten(scaleValue);
                        newPic.setPixel(i, j, p);
                    } else if (scaleValue < 0) {
                        p = picture.getPixel(i, j).darken(scaleValue);
                        newPic.setPixel(i, j, p);
                    }
                }
            }
            setPic(newPic);
            picture_view.setPicture(newPic.createObservable());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Without a working example, I would suggest, having a `List` of effects which you want to apply, so you can remove them if you need to.  Each time you need to, you take the original image and apply each effect to it and this becomes what you show on the screen.  When required, you could then "bake" the effects into a final picture

Answer (score 1):

As shown in [*Image processing with Java 2D*](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076764/java-se/image-processing-with-java-2d.html?page=2), you can create a `Map<String, BufferedImageOp>` that holds concrete instances of the [`BufferedImageOp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImageOp.html) interface.

```
Map<String, BufferedImageOp> ops = new TreeMap<String, BufferedImageOp>();
ColorSpace cs = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY);
ops.put("Gray", new ColorConvertOp(cs, null));
…
```

Add the `Map` key set to a `JComboBox`.

```
final JComboBox opBox = new JComboBox();
for (String key : ops.keySet()) {
    opBox.addItem(key);
}
```

In the combo's handler, invoke the image operation's `filter()` method on your target `BufferedImage`.

```
String key = (String) opBox.getSelectedItem();
BufferedImageOp op = ops.get(key);
bufferedImage = op.filter(bufferedImage, null);
```

The image below illustrates "Threshold 64" followed by "Invert". [`ImageDicer`](http://core0.staticworld.net/downloads/idge/imported/article/jvw/1998/09/imagedicer.java) is a complete example.

[image]